# How to add a dropdown on a tabpane bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a dropdown menu to a tabpane using bootstrap.

My plan is to have something similar to this mockup.
I thought of using the dropdown bootstraop, but not getting posible results :(

This part of the code I have for trying to have the scroll-able. This is a demo of what I have: http://jsbin.com/laqog/3

What components should I use instead of this?

```
<div class="btn-group">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Scrollable Menu <span class="caret"></span></button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
     <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

[image: Mockup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about to use nav bar using nav-stacked and set a maximum height and overflow as Auto:

Something like this:

```
 <div class="btn-group">               
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" style="height: 200px; overflow: auto" role="menu">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: I try your answer,but I'm noticing it breaks the design: http://jsbin.com/laqog/6 how I can prevent that?

Comment: Sorry, can't see whats wrong, could you be more specific?

Comment: Hi @estebane97 I mean to this: http://screencast.com/t/tXRpWAGCQ
I have a big empty space.